# PHP inside of Ajax page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using a simple Javascript/PHP script to create a Ajax function on my website. The problem is; My config.php (included at top of my index.php) includes a site language script with different languages like English and German. It works fine on the base of my index.php, but it somehow isn't included in the Ajax pages. So I included the Language script inside of my AjaxExamplePage.php, and than it worked. But the problem is, it doesn't share the same cookies, being set once the user changes their language.

That means that, once the user changes his/her language on the base of the website (static HTML, not a Ajax call) it **only** applies to the static HTML, and not to the Ajax page.

Example line: `<?php echo $lang["German"]; ?>`

Output on static HTML: `Deutsch`

Ouput on Ajax Page: `German` - Because it is still in English, after the user changes their language to German.

### **My Goal:**

Once the user changes his/her language on the static HTML, it should also apply to the Ajax page. So if the user changes their language to German, than the Ajax page should be in German as well.

***Javascript (Short version):***

```
function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#','');

    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pageContent_loader.php",
        data: 'page='+url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

***pageContent_loader.php:***

```
<?php

if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = $_POST['page'];

if(file_exists('content/general/'.$page.'.php'))
echo file_get_contents('content/general/'.$page.'.php');

else echo 'This page does not exist.';
?>
```

***Language.php***

```
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private');


if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
{
$lang = $_GET['lang'];

// register the session and set the cookie
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30), "/", ".domain.com");
}
else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang']))
{
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
$lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else
{
$lang = 'en';
}

switch ($lang) {

  default:
  $lang_file = 'english.php';

  case 'en':
  $lang_file = 'english.php';
  break;

  case 'nl':
  $lang_file = 'dutch.php';
  break;

  case 'fr':
  $lang_file = 'french.php';
  break;

  case 'de':
  $lang_file = 'german.php';
  break;




}

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/parts/languages/mainlang/".$lang_file;
```

(Domain.com is an example) 
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you store the selected language in a cookie? and why the cookie is not shared? Do you have different domains?

Comment: Nothing in the php shown checks for language cookie. Seems to be some missing details here

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Yes I store them in cookies. And no, it is the same domain. I'll include the Language.php file, so you can take a look at it.

Comment: An AJAX request to the same server sends along all the cookies by default. The problem is this: `echo file_get_contents('content/general/'.$page.'.php');` this will not process the php file but simply send its *textual* content, as-is. Not only does that ignore cookies, it doesn't even execute the php code in the file... didn't you notice you're getting PHP source code in your page? what you need to do is to redirect to the page instead: `header("Location: content/general/$page.php")`